# Converting date and time from response JSON in human readable format

Tags: json, regex

The date and time in a response JSON looks like this:

2019-02-17T05:28:00

I tried to convert it with Regex to the following format:

17.02.2019 at 05:28:00

But failed.

```
let string = string
    .split("T")
    .join("")
    .split("-")
    .join("");


  string = string.replace(
    /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{8})/,
    "$3$2$1$4"
  );
```

What is the right way?

Comment: `s.replace(/^(\d+)(-\d+-)(\d+)/, "$3$2$1").replace(/-/g, ".").replace("T", " at ")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture year month date and time in different groups using this regex,

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

And replace it with this,

```
$3.$2.$1 at $4
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r9h97v/1/)**

Javascript demo,

```js
var s = "2019-02-17T05:28:00"
console.log(s.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/g,'$3.$2.$1 at $4'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use a date-time handling library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which provides all sorts of nice date manipulation functionality.

You can then do things like

```
const moment = require("moment");

let formattedDate = moment.utc(isoDateVariable, moment.ISO_8601).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

It also helps you with all the general nastiness associated with dates and times in programs which you really don't want to be handling yourself.